# How to launch a desktop application from win32 c++ desktop application?

Tags: c++, windows, electron, desktop

I built a windows desktop application using Electron and packaged it.  I would like to have an application built in win32 / c++ be able to call and open my electron application.  Is their a command / class / function or feature that I can call from my win32 c++ application that will call and open my electron executable?

Comment: Use the Win32 API [`CreateProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx) function to launch external applications.

Comment: Also [ShellExecute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx) is a WinAPI function that can be used to launch external applications.

Comment: @Ron: `ShellExecute` is primarily meant for launching documents and other non-executable files (like script files). It calls `CreateProcess()` internally if the file being launched needs to start a new process, depending on how the file extension is registered. In any case, even if you use `ShellExecute()` to launch apps yourself, it is better to use [`ShellExecuteEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154(v=vs.85).aspx) instead, as it provides better and more accurate error handling than `ShellExecute()` does.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Indeed. I remember that particular discussion from my Delphi days.

Comment: I will check that out, awesome.  I imagine I can pass a string in while using the CreateProcess?

Comment: Pass in  a string as in provide a command line argument? As if you typed  `Program.exe "Command line argument"`?

Comment: @user3622460: yes, you can. `CreateProcess()` has an `lpCommandLine` parameter for that purpose